# Undefined property error in Angular.js and coffeescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to write a good in angularjs with coffeescript.
But I'm getting this error, even defining the 'post':

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

And here is the code:

```
'use strict'

class SupervisorEmployeeFactory

    @$inject = ['$http', 'myConfig', '$auth']

    constructor : (@$http, @myConfig, @$auth) ->
        return {
            getAllSupervisorEmployee: getAllSupervisorEmployee,
            getActiveSupervisorEmployee: getActiveSupervisorEmployee,
            getInactiveSupervisorEmployee: getInactiveSupervisorEmployee,
            getAbsentSupervisorEmployee: getAbsentSupervisorEmployee
        }


    getAllSupervisorEmployee = ->
        # Here is where the error happens in the 'post'. Probably in the other methods too.
        @$http.post @myConfig.url + '/someurl/' + @$auth.getToken()

    getActiveSupervisorEmployee = ->
        @$http.post @myConfig.url + '/anotherUrl/' + @$auth.getToken()

    getInactiveSupervisorEmployee = ->
        @$http.post @myConfig.url + '/otherSomeUrl/' + @$auth.getToken()

    getAbsentSupervisorEmployee = ->
        @$http.post @myConfig.url + '/otherOtherUrl/' + @$auth.getToken()



angular
.module 'heinz.dashboard'
.factory 'SupervisorEmployeeFactory', SupervisorEmployeeFactory
```

And here is the generated javascript code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var SupervisorEmployeeFactory;

  SupervisorEmployeeFactory = (function() {
    var getAbsentSupervisorEmployee, getActiveSupervisorEmployee, getAllSupervisorEmployee, getInactiveSupervisorEmployee;

    SupervisorEmployeeFactory.$inject = ['$http', 'myConfig', '$auth'];

    function SupervisorEmployeeFactory($http, myConfig, $auth) {
      this.$http = $http;
      this.myConfig = myConfig;
      this.$auth = $auth;
      return {
        getAllSupervisorEmployee: getAllSupervisorEmployee,
        getActiveSupervisorEmployee: getActiveSupervisorEmployee,
        getInactiveSupervisorEmployee: getInactiveSupervisorEmployee,
        getAbsentSupervisorEmployee: getAbsentSupervisorEmployee
      };
    }

    getAllSupervisorEmployee = function() {
      return this.$http.post(this.myConfig.url + '/someUrl/' + this.$auth.getToken());
    };

    getActiveSupervisorEmployee = function() {
      return this.$http.post(this.myConfig.url + '/anotherUrl/' + this.$auth.getToken());
    };

    getInactiveSupervisorEmployee = function() {
      return this.$http.post(this.myConfig.url + '/otherSomeUrl/' + this.$auth.getToken());
    };

    getAbsentSupervisorEmployee = function() {
      return this.$http.post(this.myConfig.url + '/otherOtherUrl/' + this.$auth.getToken());
    };

    return SupervisorEmployeeFactory;

  })();

  angular.module('heinz.dashboard').factory('SupervisorEmployeeFactory', SupervisorEmployeeFactory);

}).call(this);
```

Could you guys give me some idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem of your code is that the *this* var in the get methods wasn't the same as the *this* the $http was getting assigned to in the constructor.

I've regenerated your coffee script a little differently based on this [guide blog post](http://benhollis.net/blog/2014/01/17/cleanly-declaring-angularjs-services-with-coffeescript/).  I've also created a [working plnker](http://embed.plnkr.co/sBzOMU8hcxlEBzCzUeKL/preview) so that you can see the compiled version of the code below in action.

```
angular.module 'heinz.dashboard'
.factory 'SupervisorEmployeeFactory', ['$http', 'myConfig', ($http, myConfig) ->
    new class SupervisorEmployeeFactory    
        constructor :  ->
            @title = 'my title'    

        getAllSupervisorEmployee: ->
            # Here is where the error happens in the 'post'. Probably in the other methods too.
            $http.post myConfig.url + '/someurl/' #+ $auth.getToken()

        getActiveSupervisorEmployee: ->
            $http.post myConfig.url + '/anotherUrl/' #+ @$auth.getToken()

        getInactiveSupervisorEmployee: ->
            $http.post myConfig.url + '/otherSomeUrl/' #+ @$auth.getToken()

        getAbsentSupervisorEmployee: ->
            $http.post myConfig.url + '/otherOtherUrl/' #+ @$auth.getToken()
]
```

Comment: Edited with the generated JS.